# What maps correspond to what test chambers in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

Short of running through and dropping save points on every chamber, the easiest way to get wherever is to just `map` or `changelevel sp_a4_stop_the_box` (chapter 8, chamber 6, as an example) in the dev console.

However, this requires knowing what map is what chamber(s), and is not always obvious.  Is there a list to match up the `bsp`'s with the chambers?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Chapter 1 - The Courtesy Call

1. `sp_a1_intro1` - Relaxation Vault
2. `sp_a1_intro2` - Original 1
3. `sp_a1_intro3` - Original 2
4. `sp_a1_intro4` - Original 3 and 4
5. `sp_a1_intro5` - Original 5
6. `sp_a1_intro6` - Original 6
7. `sp_a1_intro7` - Original 7
8. `sp_a1_wakeup` - GLaDOS
9. `sp_a2_intro` - Original 19

### Chapter 2 - The Cold Boot

1. `sp_a2_laser_intro` - GLaDOS 1
2. `sp_a2_laser_stairs` - GLaDOS 2
3. `sp_a2_dual_lasers` - GLaDOS 3
4. `sp_a2_laser_over_goo` - GLaDOS  4
5. `sp_a2_catapult_intro` - GLaDOS 5
6. `sp_a2_trust_fling` - GLaDOS 6
7. `sp_a2_pit_flings` - GLaDOS 7
8. `sp_a2_fizzler_intro` - GLaDOS 8

### Chapter 3 - The Return

1. `sp_a2_sphere_peek` - GLaDOS 9
2. `sp_a2_ricochet` - GLaDOS 10
3. `sp_a2_bridge_intro` - GLaDOS 11
4. `sp_a2_bridge_the_gap` - GLaDOS 12
5. `sp_a2_turret_intro` - GLaDOS 13
6. `sp_a2_laser_relays` - GLaDOS 14
7. `sp_a2_turret_blocker` - GLaDOS 15
8. `sp_a2_laser_vs_turret` - GLaDOS 16
9. `sp_a2_pull_the_rug` - GLaDOS 17

### Chapter 4 - The Surprise

1. `sp_a2_column_blocker` - GLaDOS 18
2. `sp_a2_laser_chaining` - GLaDOS 19
3. `sp_a2_triple_laser` - GLaDOS 20
4. `sp_a2_bts1` - GLaDOS 21
5. `sp_a2_bts2`

### Chapter 5 - The Escape

1. `sp_a2_bts3`
2. `sp_a2_bts4` - Turret Assembly Line
3. `sp_a2_bts5` - Neurotoxin Generator
4. `sp_a2_bts6` - Tube ride (no gameplay)
5. `sp_a2_core` - Core Swap

### Chapter 6 - The Fall

1. `sp_a3_00` - Falling
2. `sp_a3_01` - Ruins
3. `sp_a3_03` - Initiative Intro, Alpha Pump
4. `sp_a3_jump_intro` - Blue Gel 1
5. `sp_a3_bomb_flings` - Blue Gel 2
6. `sp_a3_crazy_box` - Blue Gel 3
7. `sp_a3_transition01` - Beta Pump, Potato

### Chapter 7 - The Reunion

1. `sp_a3_speed_ramp` - Orange Gel 1
2. `sp_a3_speed_flings` - Orange Gel 2
3. `sp_a3_portal_intro` - Gamma Pump, White Gel 1
4. `sp_a3_end` - Master Pump

### Chapter 8 - The Itch

1. `sp_a4_intro` - Wheatley intro
2. `sp_a4_tb_intro` - Wheatley 1
3. `sp_a4_tb_trust_drop` - Wheatley 2
4. `sp_a4_tb_wall_button` - Wheatley 3
5. `sp_a4_tb_polarity` - Wheatley 4
6. `sp_a4_tb_catch` - Wheatley 5
7. `sp_a4_stop_the_box` - Wheatley 6
8. `sp_a4_laser_catapult` - Wheatley 11
9. `sp_a4_laser_platform` - Wheatley 12
10. `sp_a4_speed_tb_catch` - Wheatley 15
11. `sp_a4_jump_polarity` - Wheatley 16

### Chapter 9 - The Part Where…

1. `sp_a4_finale1` - Wheatley 17, This is that part.
2. `sp_a4_finale2`
3. `sp_a4_finale3`
4. `sp_a4_finale4` - That happened.
5. `sp_a5_credits` - Credits

Comment: Thanks for putting time into this. Do you have plans to include the co-op maps?

Comment: @Tom, are they not straightforward?  I don't remember

Comment: No, they are also scrambled. There are indeed less to remember, but still at some cost. Well, the hub serves well enough for when I don't know though...

Comment: @Tom throw up another question, motivate me :P

Answer (score 5):

Here's the complete list of all single player maps in order, which should give you a reasonable granularity:

```
sp_a1_intro1
sp_a1_intro2
sp_a1_intro3
sp_a1_intro4
sp_a1_intro5
sp_a1_intro6
sp_a1_intro7
sp_a1_wakeup
sp_a2_intro
sp_a2_laser_intro
sp_a2_laser_stairs
sp_a2_dual_lasers
sp_a2_laser_over_goo
sp_a2_catapult_intro
sp_a2_trust_fling
sp_a2_pit_flings
sp_a2_fizzler_intro
sp_a2_sphere_peek
sp_a2_ricochet
sp_a2_bridge_intro
sp_a2_bridge_the_gap
sp_a2_turret_intro
sp_a2_laser_relays
sp_a2_turret_blocker
sp_a2_laser_vs_turret
sp_a2_pull_the_rug
sp_a2_column_blocker
sp_a2_laser_chaining
sp_a2_triple_laser
sp_a2_bts1
sp_a2_bts2
sp_a2_bts3
sp_a2_bts4
sp_a2_bts5
sp_a2_bts6
sp_a2_core
sp_a3_00
sp_a3_01
sp_a3_03
sp_a3_jump_intro
sp_a3_bomb_flings
sp_a3_crazy_box
sp_a3_transition01
sp_a3_speed_ramp
sp_a3_speed_flings
sp_a3_portal_intro
sp_a3_end
sp_a4_intro
sp_a4_tb_intro
sp_a4_tb_trust_drop
sp_a4_tb_wall_button
sp_a4_tb_polarity
sp_a4_tb_catch
sp_a4_stop_the_box
sp_a4_laser_catapult
sp_a4_laser_platform
sp_a4_speed_tb_catch
sp_a4_jump_polarity
sp_a4_finale1
sp_a4_finale2
sp_a4_finale3
sp_a4_finale4
sp_a5_credits
```

Comment: Listing the maps is easy, what's key are what some of the more cryptic names are.