# How can you skip the intro sequence in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

Looking at the ceiling and floor and art is exhilarating and all, but if I want to just skip to the gameplay on future playthroughs rather than listen to Wheatley for those couple minutes, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to do so is restoring a save point after the initial intro. If you make a save file from the menu, it will not be automatically deleted from the game.

Answer (score 11):

Open the developer console (with <kbd>~</kbd>, after enabling it in the options), then enter the following command:

```
changelevel sp_a1_intro2
```

or [wherever else](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/what-maps-correspond-to-what-test-chambers-in-portal-2) you would like to start.  If you're not currently in a game, you might need to use the map command to start one (i don't quite fully understand the difference)

```
map sp_a1_intro2
```

Comment: The difference is that the former changes the current game setting to another map, the second starts a new instance. If you use `map`, you will not earn achievements.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to speed up that part by using `sv_cheats 1; host_timescale X` with `X` being a high value so you are quickly at the playable part. Just don't forget to use `sv_cheats 0` afterwards if you still want to get achievements.

Alternatively, you can use the positioning commands (also in cheats mode) to quickly teleport you there but then Wheatley will not be on par with you which might or might not be a problem for that part. The commands you will need are `getpos` and `setpos`, use `help` or `find` to see what parameters they need. Out of my head I think `getpos` needs nothing and `setpos` needs `X Y Z A B C` where `X Y Z` are coordinates and `A B C` are angles.

Aliasing them and putting them in one of the config files that gets loaded offers you a quick way to skip.

Comment: If I recall correctly, just resetting `sv_cheats` isn't enough.  You also need to save/load or restart the game after that.