# Returning to the "You Made Your Point" achievement room

Tags: portal-2

I finished *Portal 2* and now I'm doing the achievements. How do I return to the place in which you get the "You Made Your Point" achievement? I tried with the dev console and it gets me to the right level, but I can't get the achievements. Are they like one-time-only achievements?

Comment: As soon as you use the console to cheat your way in the game, the game disables achievements.

Comment: @Bora I don't think using the console disables achievements, but rather specific uses can.  I recall someone saying that either `map <mapname>` or `changelevel <mapname>` breaks achievements while the other is OK.

Comment: @NickT That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 7):

If you've completed the game, you should be able to select "New Game" from the main menu and jump to the start of any chapter. This should make it easier to get to specific test chambers.

Answer (score 1):

Turning on `sv_cheats` via the dev console immediately disables achievements.<sup>[1](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=23674057&postcount=1)</sup> Try save/loading or restarting the game after disabling `sv_cheats` before attempting the achievement. You'll also want to use `map` instead of `changelevel`, or achievements will be nullified.<sup>[2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20737/how-can-you-skip-the-intro-sequence-in-portal-2#comment28991_20743)</sup>

Re-loading Chapter 8 from "New Game" is another option, but the dev console is more adventurous.

Comment: A reload won't do. You will have to restart the whole game.